# ViewBag passes values in GET parameters in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to MVC.NET and I am stopped at some point while passing data from controller to view. I have two action, one is for GET and another is for POST. When I am setting ViewBag values in my POST method action, it redirects me to View but passes the values using GET in the URL hence ViewBag values are not accessible in view.

Here is snapshot of the same:

**View:**

```
<div>
<p>@ViewData["FileName"]</p>
<p>@ViewData["myName"]</p>
<p>@ViewBag.myAdd</p>
<p>@ViewBag.someData</p>
</div>

<div>
<form id="myForm" action="~/Test/Index">
    <input type="text" name="myName"/>
    <input type="text" name="myAdd" />
    <input type="file" name="myFile"/>

    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file, FormCollection data)
    {
        ViewBag.FileName = Convert.ToString(file.FileName);
        ViewBag.myName = Convert.ToString(data["myName"]);
        ViewBag.myAdd = Convert.ToString(data["myAdd"]);
        ViewBag.someData = "someData";
        return View();
    }
```

On submit of form, it redirects me to http://localhost:65077/Test/Index?myName=mYname&myAdd=MyAdddress&myFile=432f7018-d505-4b0b-8cba-505d62b5472d.png

it would be great if someone can help and explain the same to me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you make any customizations to the routing?

Comment: Try to specify how to send the form data with the method attribute in the form tag, like `<form method="get" ></form>`

Comment: What is the question? I do not understand what you are trying to do actually.

Comment: you are correct, thank you very much.! I arrived to solution now. :)

Comment: @RosdiKasim: just wanted to get the values in ViewBag from a controller. however, below feedback has helped me with solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per default form-data](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) is appended to the URL when send back to the server(GET-method). You have to change this by useing the method attribute:

```
<form id="myForm" action="~/Test/Index" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="myName"/>
    <input type="text" name="myAdd" />
    <input type="file" name="myFile"/>

    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: @RamjeeGupta If you are satisfied with my answer, you should mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Done.! even I am new here too. :)